# Idempotents in a ring of fractions of the tensor product of Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $S=\{x^0,x^1,x^2,...\}\subset \mathbb{Z}$ be the multiplicatively closed subset generated by $x$. What are the nontrivial idempotents in the total quotient ring $S^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}[i]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}[i])$?

I came across this question reading about the Chinese remainder theorem, and would like to see concrete examples of how to find the idempotents. Presumably one would find them using the isomorphism given by CRT. Could you show me the cases for $x=2$ and $x=3$?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that topic before, but thanks alot :)